# Human Readable filesizes

Tags: php, reinventing-the-wheel

I am re-inventing the wheel and would like to lay down a comprehensive filesizes function. The only issue is that I guess bit-wise operators are more efficient but I'll be darned if I can understand them.

What would you do to optimize this function?

```
function humanFileSize($bytes = 0, $f = 1024)
{
    $f = (int)$f;
    $i = 'i';
    $newsize = 0;
    $units = 'bytes';

    if($f === 1000)
    {
        $i = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $f = 1024;
    }

    if($bytes < $f)
    {
        $newsize = $bytes;
    }
    elseif($bytes < ($f * $f))
    {
        $newsize = ($bytes / $f);
        $units = ($f === 1024 ? 'K' : 'k').$i.'B';
    }
    elseif($bytes < ($f * $f * $f))
    {
        $newsize = ($bytes / $f / $f);
        $units = 'M'.$i.'B';
    }
    elseif($bytes < ($f * $f * $f * $f))
    {
        $newsize = ($bytes / $f / $f / $f);
        $units = 'G'.$i.'B';
    }
    else
    {
        $newsize = $bytes;
    }

    return number_format($newsize, 2, '.', ',').' '.$units;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/10/25/human-readable-filesize-php - also, your `$f` and `$i` are not human friendly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better method would be to store the suffixes in an array:

```
$suffix = [ '', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P' ];
```

and use a loop to compute the denomination:

```
$idx = 0;
while ($bytes > $f) {
    $bytes = $bytes / $f;
    $idx++;
}
```

and then, use a [string formatter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php):

```
return sprintf( "%.2f %s%sB", $bytes, $suffix[$idx], $i );
```

You can see it in action [here](https://eval.in/296905). The function would be:

```
function humanFileSize($bytes = 0, $f = 1024) {
    $f = (int) $f;
    $i = ($f === 1024) ? 'i' : '';
    $suffix = [ '', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P' ];
    $idx = 0;
    while ($bytes > $f) {
        $bytes = $bytes / $f;
        $idx++;
    }
    return sprintf( "%.2f %s%sB\n", $bytes, $suffix[$idx], $i );
}
```